# Parse json object in dictionary using Alamofire

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, alamofire

Hi this is my json response, How can i store "data" parameter values in Array. I am using Alamofire 4 and swift 3. I want this in array format, for loading contents in tableview.

```
 Optional({
"current_page" = 2;
data =     (
            {
        "address_location" = "place   of course";
        "category_id" = 1;
        "course_id" = 122;
        "course_title" = title;
        description = "dessription about the course";
        favorited = 0;
        "from_date" = "2017-02-16";
        image = "<path>";
        lattitude = "0.876423656";
        longitude = "6.86885314";
        price = 200;
        "subcategory_id" = 10;
        thumb = "<path>";
        "to_date" = "2017-02-16";
        "user_id" = 32332;
    },
            {
        "address_location" = "place   of course";
        "category_id" = 1;
        "course_id" = 123;
        "course_title" = title;
        description = "dessription about the course";
        favorited = 0;
        "from_date" = "2017-02-16";
        image = "<path>";
        lattitude = "0.876423656";
        longitude = "6.86885314";
        price = 200;
        "subcategory_id" = 10;
        thumb = "<path>";
        "to_date" = "2017-02-16";
        "user_id" = 1;
    }
);
message = Success;
"next_page" = 3;
"previous_page" = 1;
"status_code" = 200;
```

})

Code for API call action

```
    Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .get, parameters: ["":""], encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(_):
            if response.result.value != nil{
                print(response.result.value as Any)

                //

                self.parseData(JSONData: response.data!)

                if let jsonDict = response.result.value as? [String:Any], 
                    let dataArray = jsonDict["data"] as? [[String:Any]] {
                    self.dictionary_Course = dataArray  as? [[String:Any]] 
                    let nameArray = dataArray.flatMap { $0["address_location"] as? String }
                    print(nameArray)
                }                    
                print(self.dictionary_Course)


            }
            else
            {
            }
            break

        case .failure(_):
            print(response.result.error as Any)
            break

        }
    }
```

Comment: it is optional value . can you add code .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
Alamofire.request("url", method: .post, parameters: ["":""]).validate().responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                if let result = response.result.value {
                    let responseDict = result as! [String : Any]
                    let data = responseDict["data"] as! [Any]
                    print(data)
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Its working but how can i assign the data into array, when I try it show error "Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayI' () to 'NSDictionary' ()."

Comment: in which line you got error ?

Comment: try my updated answer . data is your array.

Comment: @KKRocks :- I am also facing the same issue, I am new to swift language. Using your answer I am able to store data in an array var testArray = [Any]()  , testArray = data as! [Any]
and I want to access testArray[0]["address_location"]. How to do this ?
I am getting error: type 'Any' has no subscript members this error

Comment: try this : testArray = responseDict["data"] as! [Any]

Comment: try with my answer and update your question if you got any error.

Comment: @KKRocks :- Sorry, but this is also not working. I am getting same error error: type 'Any' has no subscript members

Comment: Thanks a lot, now its working what I require using swift standard

Comment: accept answer if this is working .

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3.0**

Try below code, hope will help you.

```
if let result = response.result.value {
                    if let responseDict = result as? NSDictionary {
                        if let data = responseDict.value(forKey: "data") as?
                            [NSDictionary] {

                        }
                        print(data)
                    }

                }
```

Comment: I want to assign the object into array or dictionary. How can i assign var dictionary_Course = [String: String]()

Comment: yes, but you can see already data is in array of NSDictionary.